# Is it possible to pass a variable from a client script to a server script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Using Google App Maker, I'm trying to run a Client Script to get a variable, and then pass that variable to a Server Script so that it can use the same one. I can't seem to work it out.

My Client Script looks in a table called `OrderItems` and returns the `ProductNumber` of the current record.

The Client Script then calls the Server Script which should use the `ProductNumber` that the Client Script returned to run a query on another table.

**CLIENT SCRIPT**

```
var productNumberToUpdate = app.datasources.Purchase_Order_Line_Items.item.Stocked_Item_Product_Number.toString();
google.script.run.serverScript();
```

**SERVER SCRIPT**

```
var query = app.models.Inventory_Item.newQuery();
query.filters.Part_Number._startsWith = productNumberToUpdate;
var results = query.run();
var id = results[0]._key;
```

The Client Script runs successfully but the Server Script returns the error **ReferenceError: `productNumberToUpdate` is not defined**. This is unsurprising given that the variable `productNumberToUpdate` is indeed not defined, which is why I want to pass it from the Client Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass variables by using parameters in your function.

## Client script

```
var productNumberToUpdate = app.datasources.Purchase_Order_Line_Items.item.Stocked_Item_Product_Number.toString();
google.script.run.serverScript(productNumberToUpdate);
```

## Server script

```
function serverScript(productNumberToUpdate) {
  var query = app.models.Inventory_Item.newQuery();
  query.filters.Part_Number._startsWith = productNumberToUpdate;
  var results = query.run();
  var id = results[0]._key;
}
```

Comment: Can you use multiple parameters in the same way? E.g. something like `google.script.run.serverScript(productNumberToUpdate, aSecondVariable, aThirdVariable);`

Comment: Yes ofcourse! However you can also create one big object and store multiple variables in it.